# Multiple LTS upgrade with USB/iso

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

We have data limited internet access and I would like to upgrade multiple 12.04LTS machines in our agency with only downloading the 14.04LTS iso for use via a USB boot stick. Our data limit would not allow us to do the normal upgrade via the update mgr.  Can this be done without loosing the data on the machines?  Can I simply run the install over existing installation?  The computers do not have a separate /home partition.  Most of these machines are currently dual boot for compatability issues with software used.

Comment: Consider not upgrading immediately for business solutions for stability issues. I would wait until the 1st point release (around July).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Create an installation media. When installing, choose "upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04".

Comment: Will this keep my data intact?

Comment: Your /home directory won't be touched. And if it's possible, it will keep installed apps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll back up my home folder then cross my fingers